# Do I have to care about my companions in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

So far, the only attention I've paid to my companions in adventure mode is to make sure they aren't killed. Is there anything else about them that I should monitor and care about, e.g. hunger, thirst, sleepiness, equipment?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of. I don't think anyone really cares if they get killed or live either. I just use them as moving meat shields when I play with them.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can take and use their equipment after they die, so letting them die is actually beneficial in the early stages.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure they don't eat or sleep for some reason. I once was giving them my food in case they got hungry, until I ran out and started starving. I killed them for the 6 prepared fish they'd accumulated in their inventory.